# find orderId from my payload receipt json of google play(Unity) c#

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

**so when I check boughtProduct.receipt I get information about receipt containing orderId, transaction Id everything in the form of json like this**

```
{"Payload":"{\"json\":\"{\\\"orderId\\\":\\\"GPA.3456-5593-26230\\\",\\\"packageName\\\":\\\"com.Game.Company\\\",\\\"productId\\\":\\\"com.game.company.unlockall\\\",\\\"purchaseTime\\\":1657566629633,\\\"purchaseState\\\":0,\\\"purchaseToken\\\":\\\"ogpffeblkohlejehffmpjdia.AO-J1OzgoZ0k9--lCtsD7a_vdqMNtpVO0M6twn8uojIt9nX5f15aT15xS8gflnTpi-7HCg9_1DLY-TFE-NyY3RP1moIGNjvinoMmBEtLAIGd13IJe3PhGjg\\\",\\\"acknowledged\\\":true}\",\"signature\":\"ADNDAJDAJDJAJDAJDJADJA==\",\"skuDetails\":\"{\\\"productId\\\":\\\"com.game.company.unlockall\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"inapp\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Unlock All Chapters\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"Unlock All Chapters\\\",\\\"description\\\":\\\"Remove Ads and Unlock All Chapters\\\",\\\"price\\\":\\\"\\u20a9160.00\\\",\\\"price_amount_micros\\\":160000000,\\\"price_currency_code\\\":\\\"INR\\\",\\\"skuDetailsToken\\\":\\\"AEuhpteuwINhyl241tHPoLuXb\\\"}\"}","Store":"GooglePlay","TransactionID":"ogpffeblkohlejehzgoZ0k9--lCtsD7a_vdqMnX5f15aT15xS8gflnTpi-7HCg9_1DLY-GNjvinoMmBEtLAIGd13IJe3PhGjg"}
```

**So I want to retrieve orderId from this. I dont know how to do this.**
**I tried using Dictionary like this**

```
var gpDetails = (Dictionary<string,object>)MiniJson.JsonDecode(boughtProduct.receipt);
      
        var gpJson = (string)gpDetails["json"];
        var gpSign = (string)gpDetails["signature"];

        Debug.Log(gpSign + " sign"); 
        Debug.Log(gpJson + " json"); //or try this


            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in gpDetails) //or try this
            {
                Debug.Log("Key = {0}, Value = {1}"+
                    kvp.Key);
                
            }
```

**But I'm getting error no key found.**
**What should I do?**

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did like this and it worked easily

```
char[] charsToTrim = { '\\', '"', ':', ',' };
string orderId = getBetween(Payload, "orderId", "packageName").Trim(charsToTrim);


 string getBetween(string strSource,string strStart, string strEnd)
    {
        if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
        {
            int Start, End;
            Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
            End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
            return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
        }

        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json is quite complicated and triple serialized. You have to download and install Newtonsoft.Json for Unity3d

```
     using Newtonsoft.Json;

    var gpDetails  = JObject.Parse(json);
    gpDetails["Payload"] = JObject.Parse((string)gpDetails ["Payload"]);
    gpDetails["Payload"]["json"] = JObject.Parse((string)gpDetails["Payload"]["json"]);

 var gpSign = (string)gpDetails["Payload"]["signature"]; // ADNDAJDAJDJAJDAJDJADJA==

 Debug.Log(gpSign + " sign");
```

Answer (score 0):

You just needed one step more.

```
var jsonDetails = (Dictionary<string,object>)MiniJson.JsonDecode(gpJson);
string orderId = (string)jsonDetails["orderId"]; // this is your orderId
```